# google map javascript api v3 not working on app build by xcode 7

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm updating the hybrid app developed by IBM Worklight 6.1.02-20150725 for android, ios and windows 8. The app includes a map feature using google map javascript api v3. I build for all environments in eclipse. After that compile for iOS using XCode 7. The map does not display. Once I compile the same code using XCode 6, the map has no issue. Android and Windows app are working fine.

Could anyone advice this issue or any link that I could get reference?

In head section in index.html, I'm using following link.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&language=en&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

If I use below code to check google map, it prompt the alert.

```
if(!(typeof google==='object' && typeof google.maps === 'object')){
        alert("error loading map.");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this has anything to do with Worklight. If you are compiling in Xcode 7 then you also need to make sure that you have Bitcode disabled as well as have correctly setup the application with ATS support (or disabled it).

Read more here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I updated the  Info.plist by using Whitelist method and compile it. After that I tested on simulator/device  but the issue is still not solve.  
Therefore updated again by using Disable ATS method and compile it. After that I tested on simulator/device and the issue is solve.